# Am I the only one who only sees these job ads?

Tags: discussion, advertising

Are those ads optimized for me, or does everyone else see them?
[image: I guess ads know that I want to resign before I do]

Comment: FWIW, the jobs ads are visible even when you earn the 'see fewer ads' privilege (it's the banners that go away) so everyone gets them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those ads in the sidebar (the job ads) are selected for you based on your location and your Stack Overflow browsing history. You can find out what data we're using, what our models think of you, or turn off personalization [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data)